# Failed updating table for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, refresh, sql-workbench-j

I am using AWS Redshift to run the query.

The query contains **create table** and **join with existing tables** procedure.

There is an `updated_at` field for the new table after all procedures, which is current time.

After all procedures, `updated_at` is at current time. However, if I click the 'Refresh' button using SQL Workbench J, this field changed to last time it was successfully queried.

I think this means table is failed updated, how could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that every time you click 'refresh', that field is changing? Is it just when you are querying, or when you are updating? Please edit your question to show examples of this behaviour.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks and I just figured out I need to select 'autocommit' under connection profile, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Select 'autocommit' under connection profile page works for me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! That commit stuff can be annoying.